# Issue with UITextField values in custom cell while scrolling fast ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, custom-cell

I have a simple table with custom cells each containing a textfield. In **cellForRowAtIndexPath:** I create and initialize each cell depending on **indexPath.row**:

```
case 0:
{
    CellIdentifier = @"TextEditCell";
    TextEditCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [cell configureCellWithText: [self.valueArray objectAtIndex:0]
                    placeholder: @"value no.0"]

    [cell performAction: @selector(saveValue0:)
        forControlEvent: UIControlEventEditingDidEnd
               inTarget: self];

    return cell;
}
```

**configureCellWithText:placeholder:** sets text and placeholder of cell's textField.
**performAction:forControlEvent:inTarget** refers directly to textField and saves the value of textField to local array to be accurate when used again.

Problem occurs, when I scroll the table fast. Values from different cells copy to another cells and modify local array. I can't find out why it happens. Anyone have any idea? I can provide more code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are reusing the cells and configureCellWithText is being run after the cell is reused. To solve this you could:

1. Don't reuse cells - But this would really hurt your performance.
2. If you are running on 6.0 you can use `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` to cancel the text setting action when the cell scrolls off screen.
3. You can create a flag in your custom cell class that you set when you dequeue a cell.

**Edit**

Because I do not know how your cell works. It is hard for me to give you anything more then a sudo code concept.

Here is my sudo code:

Tableview Cell for row...
 - dequeue cell
 - [cell cancel_previous_action]
 - set new actions.

Comment: Options 1 and 2 aren't good enough for me. Can you provide more details about the third one? I created a flag in my TextEditCell class - how should I handle it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Moreover, in my code each cell has the same CellIdentifier - should I diversificate it for each cell? Does this CellIdentifier used in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` have to be the same as in `loadNibNamed:` function?

(please edit your original answer - for next generations)